# simple data encryption with javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm forwarding my visitors from a checkout page to `/store/order/view/?id=735`, but I don't want them to be able to view just anyone's order, so I need to encrypt the 735.  What's the best way to do this so Javascript can encrypt it and PHP/MySQL can decrypt it?

What about instead of ?id=735 I do `?key=735-[TIMESTAMP_ORDER_WAS_PLACED]`, do you think that's secure enough?

Comment: Obfuscation != security.

Comment: @middaparka: This is exactly what i thought when i read the question! ;)

Comment: @elusive - I dare say it'll be "good enough" until someone works out how to decode it, and then it'll be too late. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: Right. And it'll be really easy to decode, since the JavaScript part is public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. You should be making sure that no user can access pages/records that do not belong to him (server-side). Doing this client-side does not provide any security. Keep in mind that anybody can read your JavaScript and thus will be able to do whatever he wants (breaking an encryption system is *really* easy when you know how something is encoded, exactly). Do not do this and use a server-side session-based payload-secured system. That will be much safer.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this, **secure it server-side** *always*, nothing is secure if you do it in JavaScript - on the contrary it's *very* easy to break.

Via sessions or whatever mechanism you want, the server shouldn't serve an order page to anyone who shouldn't be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make it so that only logged in visitors associated with the order in question can see this page?

This would be a *much* safer approach that attempting to obfuscate the order ID.

Comment: We don't want to require a user to be logged in

Comment: No offence, but I'd really, really recommend having a re-think about this.

Comment: its not required, just identify users unobtrusively and show their respective orders

Answer (score 0):

Rather than encrypt the order ID would it be feasible to either use sessions or post variables instead?  Implemented correctly, sessions especially, would be more secure that passing variables around on querystrings.  As a general rule all security should be handled by the server not the invoking client.  Getting the client to do that work will end in tears.

However, if you do go down the query string route and assuming that you are generating the page with the link in PHP you can use the mcrypt_encrypt /  mcrypt_dencrypt functions in PHP to create the link and then decrypt when the request comes in.

That said, you will still need a unique encryption key to encrypt/decrypt and that would be the PHP session id.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are not logged in, you can either use a session, or a suitably long randomly generated ID.

The former has the disadvantage of possibly timing out, and the latter has the disadvantage of other people possibly being able to view the order, but that shouldn't happen unless the user disseminates the URL somehow (this might include leaving it in the browser history of a public computer, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Some options (from least to most preferrable) and thoughts:

Option 1) You could use some sort of less-guessable hash instead of the orderid.  This still is not secure, it's just making the id harder to guess.

Option 2) You could use a session id with a cookie stored on the user's computer.  This is still problematic because you are now limiting the viewing of that order to a single computer.  But at least it's a bit more secure.

Option 3) You could also, as part of the checkout process, "fake" an account for the user.   As part of the process, make sure you collect their email address.  When the order is completed, send them an email with a random password (which is stored with the order) and a link to view their order.  This is still less than ideal, because email is not a secure transport mechanism for a password.

Option 4) Make users have proper accounts that orders are associated with.

Even if the order is protected via some sort of passwording mechanism, You should still obscure any order url via some sort of hash.  I'd suggest:

```
md5(order_id + time() + random_salt_value)
```

Finally, do all of this server-side.  Anything generated by javascript has to be considered as "input from the user", and should never be fully trusted.  If you have to have a javascript based workflow, have ajax endpoints for all of this.